Why can't I use a .NET 8 DLL from my .NET Framework 4.7.2 Windows Forms App?
Update (8/2/204) to clarify my question:
When trying to consume a DLL (.NET 8.0) from my Windows Forms App (.NET Framework 4.7.2), I get the "Exception Unhandled" shown in the screenshot below. Why do I get this error and how do I resolve the error?
Original
I have a

Class library created using C# and Visual Studio 2022 ElabAddInMetricsDb
Windows forms app (.NET Framework) created using C# and Visual Studio 2022 ElabAddInMetricsDbDemo

In VS for the class library, I configured the Target Framework:

In VS for the Windows forms app (.Net Framework), I configured the Target Framework:

In the Windows forms app (.Net Framework), I added a ref to the class library DLL:

When I build and the execute the Windows forms app , I get:

So, am I missing runtime version 8 software, or, is there a mismatch between my class library and Windows App, or something else?
Note: See below. Control Panel -> Programs for my dev machine shows .NET SDK 8
~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
FYI
My development machine is running Windows 10 Enterprise, 22H2, 64 bit and Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise.
Control Panel (filter = .net) shows:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64 shows:


What if you create the WinForms app also targeting .NET 8?

Have you installed the System.Runtime package in your VS project, and what is its version number?

.Net projects can only use libraries targeting the same, or lower .net version. So .Net framework projects cannot use .Net 8 libraries. This should give an error if you are using a regular project reference. The simplest fix is just to change your winforms app to .Net 8.
You could also change your library to target .Net framework, or .Net standard. The later would make the library usable for both .Net framework and .Net 5+ projects.

I now see that my original question missed the mark because it stated the problem I encountered and not what my goal was. As a result, your answer is missing vital details. But again, my fault. See my updated question and my answer.

Thanks to JonasH for explaining "why" (".Net projects can only use libraries targeting the same, or lower .net version".) and providing the summary answer for "how to fix it" ("change your winforms app to .Net 8").
After pulling the pieces together from many searches, the procedures below worked for me
I made a clean slate:

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022. In my case, this was 17.10.something
I uninstalled all versions of .NET SDK (in my case, this was 5.0 and 8.0)

Reinstalled stuff:

I installed .NET 8.0 SDK


Note: I believe you can skip the previous step and then add .NET 8.0 as a
component of the Visual Studio 2022 install, but I think installing
the SDK gives you more "stuff" - not sure what, though.


I installed Visual Studio 17.10.5 (.NET 8.0 requires a minimum of 17.8)
I installed the .NET Upgrade Assistant extension (From Visual Studio: Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Browse for .NET Upgrade Assistant, Install)

Rebuilt everything:

I used VS to rebuild my existing class library (DLL) specifying a target framework of .NET 8.0
I opened my existing Windows Forms App (.NET Framework 4.7.2), used the .NET Upgrade Assistant to upgrade it to .NET 8.0, re-established the reference to the class library (DLL), built the app.

Result: The upgraded Windows Forms app worked fine with the .NET 8.0 class library (DLL)
Note: If you want to use a .NET SDK preview (e.g., .NET 9.0) in VS, you'll have to set a VS option:


8/4/2024 UPDATE

Thanks to Jimi for teaching me about the existence of the two Windows Forms templates. Previous to his comment, I was only aware of the .NET Framework template.

So, here all the scenarios and actions I'm currently aware of. It goes without saying that you'll have to manually install .NET 6.0, 8.0, or 9.0 SDKs (currently, 9.0 is a preview) to use them. For example, I had to manually install .NET 8.0 SDK and .NET Framework 4.8.1 in order to use them for my various projects.

Note: As suggested by JonasH, I would hesitate to (1) "change your library to target .Net framework". Based on https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/dotnet-standard, my class library (DLL) would need to target .NET Standard 2.0 which seems like a severe security risk because of it's age. I say this because i tried it and VS showed a security error for .NET Standard 2.0 in the Error list when I built the class library.

I just opened Visual Studio and attempted to create a Winforms project, and .NET 6, 7, and 8 are all selectable. Also, it seems you edited your question to the point that it no longer matches the title. If you are encountering a new issue I would suggest posting a new question with an updated title.

@Ramza you edited your question to the point that it no longer matches the title: Disagree. The original title stated the error encountered when I tried to consume a .NET 8.0 DLL from a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Winforms app. I changed the question to ask why I can't do that instead of asking about the error. If you're seeing target frameworks NET 6,-8 when creating a new Winforms project, perhaps you could compose an answer showing us what versions of .NET framework, .NET SDK, and Visual Studio you're using, and whether you needed the extension. Just the fact that it works for you isn't helpful.

When creating a new or existing Windows Forms app (.NET Framework), I don't see .NET 8.0: of course you don't. .NET Framework and .NET (previously .NET Core) are two different things. You have to pick the Windows Forms app template -- .NET Framework's most recent is 4.8.1. It's also the last major / minor version, those won't be updated anymore. Just maintenance / security updates versions

@Jimi I agree. You're preaching to the choir :-). That's the point I'm making with my comment to @Ramza. I don't understand how @Ramza can be seeing what @Ramza says he's seeing: I just opened Visual Studio and attempted to create a Winforms project, and .NET 6, 7, and 8 are all selectable

Because they picked the Windows Forms app template instead of the Windows Forms app (.NET Framework) template (two different templates that make use of .NET, the former, and .NET Framework, the latter). What you wrote doesn't acknowledge this fact at all, hence my comment

@Jimi: I didn't intend to ignore the distinction between a Windows Forms Application and Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework). To be frank, I wasn't clear on the distinction between the two, or even the existence of the Windows Forms Application as a separate template until I read your last comment (I have a ways to go before I'll be a knowledgeable .NET programmer). I've modified my answer to summarize all scenarios I'm currently aware exist. If you downgraded my answer, perhaps my modification will reverse the downgrade :-)
